Can I apply for the Diversity Visa Lottery while studying in US on a J-1 Visa?
I am a British student currently studying at university in the US on a study exchange year on a J-1 visa. I intend to apply to convert my non-immigrant J-1 visa to a non-immigrant F-1 visa in May 2025, so that I can stay at the US university until 2027 to complete my degree. Thankfully I do not have a 2 year home country requirement on my current J-1 visa.
If I apply for the immigrant Diversity Visa Lottery in Oct 2024, will my J-1 visa be cancelled, on the basis that it demonstrates intent to immigrate to the US, contravening the rules of the J-1 visa? Or is it only if I actually win the Lottery in May 2025 and then complete the DS-260 form to apply for a Green Card that my J-1 visa is at risk of being cancelled?
Although I am keen to enter the Lottery, I don’t want to jeopardise my studies in the US.

Yes, you can register for the DV lottery if otherwise eligible, no matter if you are in the US or outside. If you are selected and you are in the US, you have the option of getting a green card via Adjustment of Status inside the US, or via Consular Processing for an immigrant visa at a US consulate abroad.
Immigrant intent doesn't affect your status while in the US. You just need to continue to meet the requirements of your status. If you leave the US and wish to return, you might be denied entry or denied a visa (if you need to apply for a visa at the consulate) for immigrant intent.
Neither registering for the DV lottery, nor being selected in the DV lottery, necessarily means you have immigrant intent for a particular entry. Immigrant intent is a subjective determination by the officer at each entry.

I don't believe that your current status is impacted by applying for a different type of visa. So your current J1 status will not be impacted by applying for the Diversity Visa lottery.
However say for example after your application, if you were to make a trip outside of the US and then attempt to come back; there can be potential problems. By applying for an immigrant visa you have demonstrated immigration intent, it's upto the CBP officer to decide if they admit you or not.
Lastly for my personal thoughts, I think this is a pretty silly idea. You're a student and have a clear pathway to permanent residence in the USA. J1 -> F1 -> OPT -> H1B or a direct greencard application. Instead of focussing on working your ways towards this, you seem to fascinated by playing the lottery and hoping to get lucky. I'd personally focus on the path where you work towards your eventual American citizenship, it's not quick and it's hard work but it's more likely to get you to where you want to go.

"You're a student and have a clear pathway to permanent residence": that's not necessarily true.  Not everyone who qualifies for J-1 or F-1 is going to find a sponsor; in some cases they're almost guaranteed not to find one.  Even for those who do, the H-1B route can be stressful and time consuming.  Entering the lottery is certainly not silly as long as one has a realistic view of the chances and continues to pursue whatever other options they have in case they don't succeed in the lottery.

I suppose another strategy that emreges from your line of thought is to start buying lottery tickets. Win a million dollars, invest that I'm the EB5 program. Easiest way to get a green card, eh?

If you play the lottery, it isn't necessary to quit your job.  Similarly, if you enter the green card lottery, it isn't necessary to abandon your H-1B visa.  You can pursue both at once, which has a greater chance of success than pursuing only one.  But if OP's course of study is something like history of political philosophy, the H-1B route isn't going to be as simple as for someone studying geographical information systems.

How does anything the OP wrote suggest she is “fascinated” by the lottery or otherwise not working towards anything else?
